# How do you call a function which takes a tuple of two as an argument and returns a tuple of two as a result in Scala?

Tags: scala, fibonacci

I am very new to Scala. I have been assigned the task of coding the Fast Fibonacci algorithm. I am finding it difficult when it comes to actually calling the function.  The function takes a tuple of two and returns a tuple of two as a result. I don't know if my logic for fibStep is correct but I will get to that as soon as I can actually test the function. The following is what I have so far:

```
def fastFib(x: Long ): Long = {
def fibStep(x:(Long, Long)): (Long, Long) = {
   //setting temporary variables a and b
   def a = x._1
   def b = x._2

   //applying the fast Fibonacci algorithm
   def c = a * (b * 2 - a)
   def d = a * a + b * b

   if (c+d % 2 == 0) return (c,d)
   else return (d, c+d)
  }

  def tuple = (x-1,x-2)
  return fibStep(tuple)
 }
```

I need to pass the tuple (x-1,x-2) to fibStep. How do I do it? Thanks

Comment: rename the tuple parameter in the inner function `fibStep` to `tx` for example, it shadows the `x` parameter from the `fastFib` function

Comment: use `val a`, `val b`, `val c`, `val d` instead of `def` to avoid recomputation each time they are referenced. Also, `val (a, b) = x` for cleaner code. And you don't need `return` keyword if it's in the last statement. So, `if (..) (c,d) else (d, c+d)` and `fibStep(tuple)` in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of problems here.

`def` is used to define functions

`val` should be used to define variables

`return` should not be used. You 'return' a result simply by it being the last value in an expression.

A tuple is defined simply using parenthesis:

`val myTuple = (1,2)`

With this information you should be able to make a better attempt at it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in return statement. You trying to return tuple, instead of Long.

Fix:

```
def fastFib(x: Long ): Long = {     
   ...
   return fibStep(tuple)._1  // or ._2
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if your algorithm is correct